# Create BehaviorSubject from Observable

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java

Say I have an `observableA` which gets data from network and emits it, if I do subscription to this observable each time it tries to request data from network which is heavy.

I want to create BehaviorSubject and connect it to observableA, so that any other threads/objects will subscribe to BehaviorSubject in order to get latest emitted data.

So far I couldnt manage it to code. I cannot create empty BehaviorSubject and call inside observableA, because they are not related to each other.
I cannot subscribe to observableA and get BehaviorSubject as observer, any idea how can I accomplish it? or maybe even better?

Comment: Why can't you subscribe? This answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54352114/3671939

Answer (score 4):

You can use `multicast`. E.g.,

```
Observable<String> o = ...;
ConnectableObservable<String> co = o.multicast(BehaviorSubject.<String> create());
co.connect();
co.subscribe(...);
co.subscribe(...);
co.subscribe(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar scenario in javascript where I wrapped promise within Rx and I didn't want to make network call again when I subscribe to observable. This is how I ended up implementing:

```
   subject = new Rx.AsyncSubject();
   observable = Rx.Observable.fromPromise(....).subscribe(subject);
```

You can now consume the promise response as subject.subscribe(...) and it will always emit promise result from subject as we are using AsyncSubject (AsyncSubject - Represents the result of an asynchronous operation. The last value before the OnCompleted notification, or the error received through OnError, is sent to all subscribed observers).

Answer (score 0):

In Rx.NET we'd use one of the [Publish](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.publish(v=vs.103).aspx) overloads that accepts an `initialValue` parameter.  Essentially, it's just a shorter way of doing a multicast like zsxwing described.  I'm not sure whether Rx.Java offers these overloaded `Publish` methods.