# How to convert an Observable into a BehaviorSubject?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject

I'm trying to convert an Observable into a BehaviorSubject. Like this:

```
a$ = new Observable()
b$ = BehaviorSubject.create(new BehaviorSubject(123), a$)
//
```

I have also tried:

```
a$ = new Observable()
b$ = new BehaviorSubject(a$, 123)
//
```

And:

```
a$ = new Observable()
b$ = a$.asBehaviorSubject(123)
//
```

And:

```
a$ = new Observable()
b$ = a$.pipe(
  toBehaviorSubject(123)
)
//
```

But none of these works. For now I have to implement like this:

```
a$ = new Observable()
b$ = new BehaviorSubject(123)
a$.subscribe(b$)
//
```

This would be a little bit ugly in a class:

```
class Foo() {
  a$ = new Observable() // Actually, a$ is more complicated than this.
  b$ = new BehaviorSubject(123)

  constructor() {
    this.a$.subscribe(this.b$)
  }
}
```

So, is there a simpler way to convert an Observable to a BehaviorSubject without using class constructor?

---

This is my real case:

```
export class Foo {
  autoCompleteItems$ = new BehaviorSubject<string[]>(null)
  autoCompleteSelected$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(-1)
  autoCompleteSelectedChange$ = new Subject<'up'|'down'>()

  constructor() {
    this.autoCompleteItems$.pipe(
      switchMap((items) => {
        if (!items) return EMPTY
        return this.autoCompleteSelectedChange$.pipe(
          startWith('down'),
          scan<any, number>((acc, value) => {
            if (value === 'up') {
              if (acc <= 0) {
                return items.length - 1
              } else {
                return acc - 1
              }
            } else {
              if (acc >= items.length - 1) {
                return 0
              } else {
                return acc + 1
              }
            }
          }, -1)
        )
      })
    ).subscribe(this.autoCompleteSelected$)
  }

  doAutoComplete = () => {
    const item = this.autoCompleteItems$.value[this.autoCompleteSelected$.value]
    // do something with `item`
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the usecase for this? You can typically use just `merge`. Using `subscribe` is the most Rx way I think.

Comment: Which is the reason you want to convert an Observable to a BehaviourSubject? Is it because you want to have access to the last value? If this is the case you can look at `shareReply` or a sequence of `publishReplay` and `refCount`

Comment: @Picci Yes. I want to have access to the latest value. Thanks for advise! I'm going to have a look on these APIs.

Comment: @Picci Actually I want to write something like `b$.value` or `b$.getValue()`.

Comment: With subjects, `value` and `getValue` are code smells and are best avoided.

Comment: @cartant Thanks for advise. I think I should refactor my code...

Answer (score 86, accepted):

No need to convert it.

Just create a subject and attach observable to it with : `obs.subscribe(sub)`

example:

```
var obs = new rxjs.Observable((s) => {setTimeout(()=>{s.next([1])} , 500)}) //observable
var sub = new rxjs.BehaviorSubject([0]) //create subject
obs.subscribe(sub) //<----- HERE ----- attach observable to subject
setTimeout(() => {sub.next([2, 3])}, 1500) //subject updated
sub.subscribe(a => console.log(a)) //subscribe to subject
```

**Note**: `obs.subscribe(sub)` is equivalent to :

```
obs.subscribe({
  next: v => sub.next(v),
  error: v => sub.error(v),
  complete: () => sub.complete()
})
```

[Run it online](https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/zYGQjqe?editors=1010)

Comment: A Subject can be considered an Observer, so it can be use directly as an argument for the subscribe. obs.subscribe(sub). Instead of manually wiring next to sub.next, error to sub.error, etc.

Comment: No `unsubscribe`?

Comment: @SkorunkaFrantišek Say rather `complete`.

Answer (score 27):

This is how I convert my Observables to BehaviorSubjects:

```js
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

export function convertObservableToBehaviorSubject<T>(observable: Observable<T>, initValue: T): BehaviorSubject<T> {
    const subject = new BehaviorSubject(initValue);

    observable.subscribe(subject);

    return subject;
}
```

Comment: After the `return`, does subscription gets unsubscribed? How are we sure that there is no  possible memory leak?

Comment: @JuozasRastenis No, this code doesn't any unsubscribing - obviously. But you could implement that functionality yourself. This snippet is just meant to be a helpful starting point for your own solution.

Comment: Maybe by using take(1)?

Answer (score 9):

Pipe the observable into `shareReplay(1)`. Any subscribers to `shareReplay(1)` will:

1. immediately receive the last most recent event emitted from the source
2. any future events emitted by the source.

This makes it act exactly as a behavior subject.

https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/shareReplay

```js
const { Subject, shareReplay } = rxjs; 
    
console.log("Start")
let source = new Subject();
    
let converted = source.pipe(shareReplay(1));
    
    
console.log("Subscription A starting")
converted.subscribe(s=>console.log("Subscription A emits",s));

console.log("Source next 1")
source.next(1);

console.log("Subscription B starting")
converted.subscribe(s=>console.log("Subscription B emits",s));

console.log("Source next 2")
source.next(2);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@7.5.7/dist/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Note that `shareReplay()` never unsubscribes and keeps the results forever. See the docs.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE 2023/11 (rxjs 7.8.1)

Seems like there is still no way to get a real BehaviorSubject from an Observable without using **subscribe(...)** somewhere

Based on the answer from [tmuecksch] here is a version which considers unsubscription:

```js
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

export function convertObservableToBehaviorSubject<T>(
    observable: Observable<T>,
    initValue: T,
    destroyed$: ReplaySubject<boolean>
): BehaviorSubject<T> {
    const subject = new BehaviorSubject(initValue)
    observable.subscribe(subject).add(destroyed$)
    return subject
}
```

The last parameter destroyed$ is something that emits, if this behaviorsubject is not needed anymore. For example, if this behaviorsubject is part of an angular component, it could make sense to call it when the component gets destroyed.

Answer (score -3):

I have pretty concerns about the use case too. But here it comes a solution, feel free vote down as long you leave feedback too. Since `BehaviourSubject` and any other `Subject` are `Observables`,

```
import { BehaviorSubject, from } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';


const source$ = from([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]);
const bs = new BehaviorSubject('start')
    .pipe(
        mergeMap(() => source$)
    );

bs.subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! But `bs` is still an observable and `bs.value` is undefined.

Comment: Yeah I still struggle with this use case but I think that value is undefined because the returned value by merge map is instance of an Observable not the Behaviour subject