# RxJS operator for making an observable wait for a value from another observer?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have a situation with two observables...

```
Observable1 - an array of objects
Observable2 - a boolean
```

I want to combine these so that observable1 is on activated if observable2 changes and has a boolean true value.

Suggestions?

Comment: `merge`, `combineLatest` or maybe just `switchMap`? I don't understand what exactly you want to do,

Comment: I'm using a service in an Angular 10 app to control the selection and deletion of objects.  Observable1 is the list of objects,  and Observable2 represents the 'delete' action.

Comment: [you can convert Observable2 to Subject or BehaviorSubject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53372138/how-to-convert-an-observable-into-a-behaviorsubject)

Comment: I don't get the question, could you please explain it more clearly?